# Question like imperative sentence

Tags: imperative-sentences

Is it possible to use the structure of a question but to make commands?

Like these ones.

> Don't you talk back to me young Landy.
>
> Oh, Don't you worry. I'll be fine.

I have another question.

Can simple present and present continuous also be used as imperative?

> You sit right there.

Think about a situation where someone is about to leave but you don't want them to. So you tell them: You sit right there.

Obviously you're not stating a fact that that person is sitting there but you're giving them command.

I have seen this kind of sentences in movies and series a lot(and I mean a lot ).

Am I right about them? 
If they are not imperative, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

Your first two examples don't have the structure of questions. They are imperative. If you are asking whether the meanings can be cast as questions, I can't imagine it.

"You sit right there." is definitely imperative. It's not a continuous form.

You might say "You are sitting right there". That would be continuous, and not imperative.  It's not a likely thing to say.

Comment: Imperative: *"And where will we sit? Let's see … You, Sally! You are sitting right there!*

Comment: Well, with the exclamation point!  Still, I'd say that's declarative, with imperative force.

Comment: I don't know. I'm inclined to say it follows intent more: *"Say, Sally … "* [gestures with his gun] *"I really think you should sit over there …"* In both cases, whether accompanied by an exclamation or a subtle implication, a command is being given that's exhorting action. I don't think you can have imperative force (although you can have declarative force). The main thing is if it's a command or not.

Comment: Agreed, you'd better do it. But maybe that's not grammatically an imperative.

Comment: According to *Practical Grammar*, by Maxine Ruviinsky, the imperative mood is "to give a command or request … Note that the subject of the imperative is *you*, often implied rather than stated." The classic examples are just how it's commonly phrased. But the two variations I gave are still examples of a command or request.

Comment: So, imperatives are used to give commands or requests. The variations you gave are examples of commands or requests. That does not imply that those are examples of grammatical imperatives.

Comment: From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*imperative*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imperative#h2): "**2** : the grammatical mood that expresses the will to influence the behavior of another or a verb form or verbal phrase expressing it." If you still think that *imperative* in this sense is something distinct from *grammatical imperative*, I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: No, grammatical imperative is imperative mood. It doesn't include declarative sentences used to influence behavior. Otherwise, a statement like "Nice business you have here. It would be a shame if anything happened to it." could be interpreted as an imperative. I think you are commingling grammar and semantics. But if you still disagree, that's alright. I disagree too. Have a good day! (That's just hortatory, not a command.)

Comment: Why don't they have the structure of a question!? I mean if i wanted to ask someone if they worry about me or not, I would say : Don't you worry about me? So it can be a qestion, right? And my qestion was that if this question-like sentences can be imperative which according to your answer they can and they are.

Comment: No, you can ask "Don't you worry about me?" as a question, and you can say "Don't you worry about me!" as a command (an imperative), but they are two different things, two different grammatical structures using the same words in the same order, but pronounced with different intonations.

Comment: Well then I guess my definition of structure is wrong.